# Neo4J Enforce Unique Relationships bertween Nodes when reading from CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, schema, graph-databases

In graph building using Neo4j I am having an issue when importing from CSV import a sizable amount of nodes and relationships.  This is a recreation of what is happening: The example has 4 `ClinicalTrial` that share `Treatment` and `TreatmentType` nodes and `IN_CLASS` relationships.  When these are created reading from a CSV, the relationships endup duplicated. **Is there a way of using APOC schemas or any other tool to prevent this from happening ?**  I know I can remediate it with cypher, but I want to prevent it from happening.

This cypher code re-creates what occurs when reading from CSV (NOTE: the cypher code below is just to recreate what occurs sequentially when reading from CSV):

```
MERGE (c1:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT1"})
MERGE (t1:Treatment {name: "Caffeine", tClass: "Drug"})
MERGE (tc1:TreatmentClass {name: "Drug"})
MERGE (c1)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t1)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc1)
    
MERGE (c2:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT2"})
MERGE (t2:Treatment {name: "Placebo", tClass: "Drug"})
MERGE (tc2:TreatmentClass {name: "Drug"})
MERGE (c2)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t2)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc2)
    
MERGE (c3:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT3"})
MERGE (t3:Treatment {name: "Placebo", tClass: "Supplement"})
MERGE (tc3:TreatmentClass {name: "Supplement"})
MERGE (c3)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t3)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc3)

MERGE (c4:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT4"})
MERGE (t4:Treatment {name: "Placebo", tClass: "Supplement"})
MERGE (tc4:TreatmentClass {name: "Supplement"})
MERGE (c4)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t4)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc4)
```

I also tried this APOC schema, but it does not work. A similar schema enforcement without the tClass restrain used to work.  It gives me the following error:

> ERROR Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed Node(23)
> already exists with label `Treatment` and property `tClass` = 'Drug'

Here is the nonworking schema:

```
// Create Schemas Clinical Trials
CALL apoc.schema.assert(
    null,
    {ClinicalTrial: ['name'],
    Treatment: ['name', 'tClass'],
    TreatmentClass: ['name']}
    ,true
)
```

This is what I want:
[image: Ideal Clinical Trial Node and Relationship Representation]

This is what I get:
[image: Actual Incorrect Neo4J Representation when importing from CSV]

Comment: Your cypher query, gives the desired graph, here https://console.neo4j.org/. Without any schema restrictions

Comment: Thanks for you comment, note that the relationship from one of the `Placebo` 
(name property) nodes to the `Supplement` has duplicated relationships.  While in the code I put there is very simple, I am trying to create a graph from a CSV with hundred of thousands rows.  Because of the multiple relationships between nodes, the creation of the model becomes very expensive, going in and removing the redundant relationships is also very expensive.

Comment: Yeah, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the query lies in these parts `MERGE (c1)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t1)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc1)`, when merging paths neo4j checks whether the whole path is non-existent or not, and then creates it. So when, this statement gets executed `MERGE (c4)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t4)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc4)`, since the whole path itself does not exists, it creates it, even though `(t4)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc4)` is present, that's why you see two relations, between same `Treatment` and `TreatmentClass` nodes. To fix this, you can simply breakdown the `MERGE` statements like this:

```
MERGE (c1:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT1"})
MERGE (t1:Treatment {name: "Caffeine", tClass: "Drug"})
MERGE (tc1:TreatmentClass {name: "Drug"})
MERGE (c1)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t1)
MERGE (t1)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc1)
    
MERGE (c2:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT2"})
MERGE (t2:Treatment {name: "Placebo", tClass: "Drug"})
MERGE (tc2:TreatmentClass {name: "Drug"})
MERGE (c2)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t2)
MERGE (t2)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc2)
    
MERGE (c3:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT3"})
MERGE (t3:Treatment {name: "Placebo", tClass: "Supplement"})
MERGE (tc3:TreatmentClass {name: "Supplement"})
MERGE (c3)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t3)
MERGE (t3)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc3)

MERGE (c4:ClinicalTrial {name: "CT4"})
MERGE (t4:Treatment {name: "Placebo", tClass: "Supplement"})
MERGE (tc4:TreatmentClass {name: "Supplement"})
MERGE (c4)-[:INTERVENTION]-(t4)
MERGE (t4)-[:IN_CLASS]-(tc4)
```

Comment: Charchit, this fixes the issue of the redundant relationships.  The problem I am having now is that it became extremely slow.  I will put that issue in another question.  Than you for your answer.

Comment: If the dataset you are importing is very large, it may take a while. Use PERIODIC COMMIT, so that data get committed at regular intervals.